# React Native Navigation header over flatlist content

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

1st

[image]

2nd

[image]

As you can see in the image (1st - before applying padding, 2nd - after applying padding), the header is covering/on top of my flatlist content, but if I give paddingTop: 80 (a constant value), it looks fine (obviously). What could be the problem here? I'm confused!

```js
const StrategyInfo = ({navigation}) => {
  const {strategyTitle} = useRoute().params;
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: strategyTitle });
  }, [navigation, strategyTitle]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <Animated.FlatList
        data={stocks}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => (
          <View style={styles.listHeader}>
            <Text>All stocks</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        contentContainerStyle={{marginHorizontal: 10}}
        keyExtractor={(_: any, index) => 'key' + index}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.exchange}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
  },
  listHeader: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
});
```

Package.json:

```
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
"firebase": "^9.6.6",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.67.2",
"react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the SafeAreaView, you can use the `useSafeAreaInsets` hook, which will give you the amount of padding to add to the top/bottom of the View to avoid those elements. You can also use the `useHeaderHeight` hook to only get the height of the header.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/ touches on useSafeAreaInsets
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight

Comment: I used the `useHeaderHeight` from `'@react-navigation/elements' package` and it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!